# How to show nodes with a flexible grid?

Tags: entities

For a website I need to show nodes with a flexible grid. There will be several rows (no specific number) and each row can contain:

- 1 full width image
- 2 50% width images
- 1 50% width image (left/right) and 1 50% width text block
- 1 full width text block

The administrator should be able to change the order of these blocks easily. I'm planning to do this with the Field Collection module, I think with this I can get this to work. But i was wondering, is there a better way to do this?

Here are two examples of what the node could look like, but ofcourse there are hundreds of different options.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) which is an alternative to Field Collection.

Comment: +1 Unlike Field Collection, Paragraphs was created specifically for this use case. I would definitely give it a try. Panels is a really flexible system, but personally I wouldn't know how to build a content type with it that allows multiple rows of pre-defined row types.

Comment: Great! Just what I was looking and hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be looking at the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module also. Excerpt from its project page:

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content manager that lets you visually design a layout and place content within that layout. Integration with other systems allows you to create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this, and even override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so that you can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained permissions.

Possibly also with 'mini-panels' added to that.

Be prepared however to invest some time in learning about this amazing modules. A great resource for learning about Panels is the (free) video training about [Learn Page manager](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-page-manager). *Panels* uses 'Page manager', which is one of the sub-modules of [Chaos tool suite (ctools)](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools)).